# Can't Set Up IPv4 Server

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I've been experimenting with sockets lately. I tried to make a simple program where a client could connect to me (host) and any text that they would enter would be sent to me. I tried to run my program on my IPv4 because I wanted to share this program with my friends that are on different PC's. Here is the host code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

print "Server socket created."

s.bind(('my actual IPv4 address here',9999))

s.listen(3)
print "Waiting for connections."

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    name = c.recv(1024)
    print name, " Connected with ", addr
    c.send(bytes('Connected to the server.'))
    while True:
        usertxt = c.recv(1024)
        print name, " said ", usertxt
        c.send(bytes(usertxt))
        if usertxt == "close":
            c.close()
        else:
            continue
```

The error that I get is "The requested address is not valid in its context" on line 7
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried: `s.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999))`

Comment: yup, i did try localhost and everything worked fine. im trying to set it up with IPv4 though

Comment: that is ip4.  You want to use the loopback address, the ipaddress then is what inbound connections would call.